Align block editor
When working in the editor mode of Gutenberg blocks the editor field aligns fully to the left. So there is no space between text/images and the left side of the editor.
This changed from one day to another.
Wordpress is fully up-to-date.
What can cause this issue?

The issue of Gutenberg blocks aligning fully to the left in the editor, leaving no space between the text/images and the left side of the editor, can be caused by a few factors. Here are some potential causes and solutions:

Theme or Plugin Conflict
A conflict with your active theme or a plugin could lead to unexpected changes in the editor's appearance.
Solution:

Temporarily switch to a default WordPress theme (like Twenty Twenty-One) to see if the issue persists. If the problem disappears, it may be related to your theme’s CSS.
Deactivate all plugins temporarily and check if the issue resolves. If it does, reactivate them one by one to identify the conflicting plugin.

Custom CSS or JavaScript
If you have added custom CSS or JavaScript (either in your theme or through a plugin), it might affect the alignment of the Gutenberg editor.
Solution:

Review any custom styles or scripts you have added. Look for any rules that might be affecting the .editor-post-title, .editor-styles-wrapper, or similar classes.
If you find conflicting styles, you may need to adjust or remove them.

Editor Styles
Sometimes, the styles loaded in the block editor might be overridden or not applied correctly, causing alignment issues.
Solution:

Check if your theme supports block editor styles by looking for a add_theme_support('editor-styles') function in your theme’s functions.php file.
Ensure that the necessary editor styles are enqueued correctly. If your theme is missing this, you can add it:

add_action('after_setup_theme', function() {
    add_theme_support('editor-styles');
    add_editor_style('style-editor.css'); // Adjust the path as needed
});


Browser Cache
Cached styles in your browser might lead to display issues, especially after an update.
Solution:

Clear your browser cache or try accessing the editor in an incognito window to see if the problem persists.

Gutenberg Plugin
If you are using the Gutenberg plugin, it might have been updated and introduced a bug affecting layout in the editor.
Solution:

Disable the Gutenberg plugin and use the core block editor to check if the problem remains. If it resolves the issue, consider reporting it to the Gutenberg development team.

JavaScript Errors
JavaScript errors can cause issues in the block editor, including layout problems.
Solution:

Open the browser’s Developer Tools (usually F12 or right-click and select “Inspect”) and check the Console for any JavaScript errors.
If errors are present, they may give you a clue about which plugin or theme is causing the conflict.
Thanks.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
